# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: xxx is not defined in react in useCallBack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I have one Home component that need to wait for requestQuery api finish then parse the response `data` and pass the `data` into Child component as following code. if I move `data` variable out of `useCallBack` and hardcode the response `data` as mock data. my code is working. However after I move the data variable into useCallBack with async function I got the error
`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: results is not defined`
How should I solve it?

```
import React, {useCallback, FC, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
export const Home: FC = () => {
  const initData = useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {

      // attempt to load based on flow
  const [hasLoadingFailed, setLoadingFailed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

    try {
      const {data, errors} = await requestQuery({num: 1});

      // if errors or no data, throw error
      if (!data || errors?.length) throw Error('Errors Retrieving Data');

      const {results = []}: QueryResponse = data;
      console.log({results}); //no problem to get results
    } catch {
      setLoadingFailed(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    initData();
  }, [initData]);

  return (
    <div><Child data={results} /></div>
  );
};
``
```

Comment: looks like result variable is undefined or null during initial render

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

I'm sure you should be seeing a linting error about calling the `useState` React hooks in a callback, which breaks the Rules of Hooks. Additionally, `results` being passed to `Child` is undefined since it's only declared within the `useCallback` hook's callback scope, not the `Home` component function scope.

## Solution

Fix the issues with the `useState` hooks and declare a `results` state to be passed to children components.

```
import React, { useCallback, FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const Home: FC = () => {
  const [hasLoadingFailed, setLoadingFailed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [results, setResults] = useState<any[]>([]); // <-- default results state

  const initData = useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const {data, errors} = await requestQuery({ num: 1 });

      // if errors or no data, throw error
      if (!data || errors?.length) throw Error('Errors Retrieving Data');

      const { results = [] }: QueryResponse = data;
      console.log({ results }); //no problem to get results

      setResults(results); // <-- update the results state
    } catch {
      setLoadingFailed(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    initData();
  }, [initData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Child data={results} />
    </div>
  );
};
```